# How to get this look in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How to get this look in Photoshop or by any other online application?

[image]

Comment: Which part of the image's look do you want to replicate? It just looks like a black and white image with high contrast so the shadow regions are completely black. Convert to greyscale then using Levels will do that in Photoshop.

Comment: Convert to gray scale -> add some guassian blur -> save it at the highest JPG compression rate.

Answer (score 1):

That's not so much a Photoshop thing as it is a photographic technique. It's just a high contrast shot with spot lighting. The Photography SE could give you pointers for reproducing this in camera.

If you must do it in Photoshop to an existing image, there is some hope.

- **Mask off the various regions of the photo** from the desired highlight to the shadow and some way to progressively adjust between the two. You could feather the shadow side, for instance.
- **Use adjustment layers with those masks applied** to get the lighting right. There are a lot of options here depending on the photo: Curves, levels, exposure, etc.
- **This style usually comes with a bit of graininess too**. If you want that, apply the film grain effect.

Comment: Just to extend: This photographic technique is called low-key photographing and is all about the lighting setup. For more info: http://www.lightstalking.com/low-key-photography

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your link isn't working, so here's another low key photography lesson: https://medium.com/@fromtherooftopsphoto/titillating-viewers-with-nudity-in-my-work-bc929758058f